# Store sync doesn't trigger request

Tags: javascript, extjs, store

For some reason my `store.sync()` command sometimes doesn't trigger no server requests.
I am not sure why this is happening. The records are always modified when calling `sync()`. I have also tried debugging and the sync command in simply omitted(skipped) without any errors. Also the failure callback on store.sync is never called.

I am out of ideas on how to debug this issue. Could you please assist.

```
    console.debug(record.dirty);          //TRUE
    console.debug(record.isValid());      //TRUE

     store.sync({
        scope:this,

        callback : function(batch, options) {
            console.debug("ok"); //never reached

        },

        failure : function(batch, options) {
            console.debug("failed"); //never reached
        }
    });
};
```

**EDIT**
I have also tried debugging on the `beforesync` event But the event handler is never called even if `snync` is triggered.

**EDIT**
Output before `snyc`

```
console.debug(record.getChanges());
```

Outputs the fields that were changed, again indicating that the record was modified.

Comment: There is only one logical reason why it could happen: record is dirty because a field with `persist:false` is dirty.

Otherwise, I would need to reproduce the issue to find out. Can you post a showcase best on http://fiddle.sencha.com

Comment: All fields have persist set to true. Making a relevant fiddle would be impossible. My use case is to complicated. Also the url and other things would not be the same. I am just looking for a guideline on debugging this issue. Not for a sollution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to debug it would be the following:

1. run the app normally
2. in console type

   `store = "get reference to the store here";`

   `store.sync = Ext.Function.createInterceptor(store.sync,function(){debugger}, store); // all in one line`

Now make the store dirty and initiate sync. The code execution stops just before `store.sync` is executed so you can call something like this from the console:

```
this.getModifiedRecords();
this.getNewRecords();
this.getRemovedRecords();
```

Or you can examine `this` variable that is store in fact at that point.

Comment: Jacob, did you try the above? Results?

Comment: I did try this. The code execution stopped as you wrote, but I was unable to find the reason at that point. Looks like the records are not detected as modified even if they are really modified and also the dirty flag indicates that.

Comment: Well, it starts to get tricky then. Can you prepare a showcase that would reproduce the behavior and that I could run locally or at https://fiddle.sencha.com?

Comment: That I understand. However, it might be the fastest route to fixing it. It is not a known issue, I haven't run into it in huge projects, so I cannot even guess w/o seeing/running it.